# Access object variable

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public $username;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->username = "User";
    }
}
```

---

```
class Post extends MY_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {        
        $data = array(
            'name'=>'CodeIgniter',
            'username' => $username
        );

        $this->template->load('post/index', $data);
    }
}
```

I don't access to `$username` in `Post` class, how to fix this problem?

Comment: So you have MY_Controller with public username property, that extends CI_Controller, and Post class that extends MY_Controller, and you want to access $username? did i understand corectly? then try $this->username

Comment: You should post this as an answer @DanIonescu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **MY_Controller** with public **username** property, that extends **CI_Controller**, and **Post** class that extends **MY_Controller** then to access username property from inside **Post** class use:

```
$this->username
```